# Python - replace all keys in nested dict according to list

Tags: python, json, nested

I have a JSON file where all the keys are numbers. 
These numbers are the index of the correct key in a list of keys I have.

Example JSON file (excuse any odd formatting, this is a simplified version of the actual file):

```
{
    "0": {
        "1": [{
            "2": 0,
            "3": {
                "4": "string"
            },
            "4": {
                "5": 2,
                "6": 1
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Example list:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

Is there a way to then replace the keys with their counterparts from the list? (as in, the key '0' would become 'a', '1' would become 'b' and so on.)

I can get it working for just the parent keys, but not any of the nested keys.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: You will need a recursive function.

Comment: What if a key is `27`? Will it become `bg`?

Comment: I would like the key 27 to become the 28th value in the list, if it was that long, just as key 0 becomes the first value :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a recursive function that transforms its argument, and then its nested values.

Use `isinstance` to handle `dict` and `list` arguments appropriately. Other values are considered "leaf nodes" and are returned unmodified.

```
import pprint

obj = {
    "0": {
        "1": [{
            "2": 0,
            "3": {
                "4": "string"
            },
            "4": {
                "5": 2,
                "6": 1
            }
        }]
    }
}

keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']


def transform(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [transform(element) for element in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {keys[int(key)]: transform(value) for key, value in obj.items()}
    else:
        return obj



print('Before:')
pprint.pprint(obj)
other = transform(obj)
print('After:')
pprint.pprint(other)
```

Comment: Nice. I guess you could also create another dictionary which represents `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, ....}` for easy mapping. But in this case it would also make it slightly easier +1.